# Replace specific date with text using Javascript

Tags: javascript

New to javascript here, and am trying to replace a specific event dates with text.  Events dates are in the format #F #d, and I'd like to instead show "Christmas" if #F #d =  December 25.  Thanks in advance.

```
const eventdate = #F #d;
let dateswap;
if (eventdate == 'December 25') {
    dateswap = "Christmas";
}
document.innerHTML = dateswap;
```

Comment: Please add your try here.

Comment: Using date/time formatting from Wordpress: https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/

Comment: That looks like it should work for December 25, however if it's any other day `dateswap` is undefined. So you want to use `document.body.innerHTML = dateswap || eventdate` if `dateswap` is undefined it will return `eventdate` instead.
Also `.innerHTML` doesn't exist on `document`, I think you mean the body with `document.body`

Comment: @Zed I don't think their code would run because the first line includes invalid syntax: `#F #d`.

Comment: @flamesdev Wow I completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement to change the variable's value if it is equal to a specific date.

```js
let date = 'December 25';
if (date === 'December 25') {
  date = 'Christmas';
}

console.log(date); // value is now "Christmas"
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally in the future it's always good to show your effort, but welcome to SO here's a freebie! :)

```js
// Let's pretend this is what's supplying your date.
const date = new Date(),
      christmasDay = new Date('December 25, 2021 00:00:01'),
      output = document.getElementById('output-example'),
      christmasMessage = 'IT IS CHRISTMAS! HO HO HO!';

// Now let's find out if it's christmas.
// First we see if month == 11 (because month works as array and starts count at 0 not 1)
// Then we check to see if the current day is the 25th with getDate()
// If the date matches we display a special christmas greeting, if not then something else.
// To see it work change "date" for .getMonth() and .getDate() below to "christmasDay"
// This way you can simulate the christmas day date to see the change.

isChristmas = (d) => {
  return d.getMonth() == 11 && d.getDate() == 25;
}

// if you wanted an if example
if (isChristmas(date)) {
  output.innerHTML=`<h1 style="color:red">${christmasMessage} - ${date.toLocaleDateString('en-US')}</h1>`;
} else {
  output.innerHTML=`<h1 style="color:blue">Sorry, not yet christmas :( - ${date.toLocaleDateString('en-US')}</h1>`;
}

// --------------------------------------------------
// Or just set a function to return accordingly
isTodayChristmas = (d) => {
  // with a ternary example
  return isChristmas(d) ? christmasMessage : d;
}

// We'll use christmas day var to ensure we're sending the christmas date for this example.
console.log(isTodayChristmas(christmasDay));
```

```html
<div id="output-example"></div>
```